# Remapping Ctrl-l in bash

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

Can one remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>l</kbd> in bash to execute more than just clear?

I know normally it just clears the screen. I'm looking to change that to clear the screen and list my `pwd` like so:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>l</kbd>:`clear;ls;`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [`bind` command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-bind-129) defines new key bindings. With the `-x` parameter, you can assign a shell snippet to a key. The quoting is a bit strange: the key must be quoted for the readline key parser, and the binding description must be quoted because it contains several shell special characters.

```
bind -x '"\C-l": clear; ls'
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this command available in osx? Would you know by some chance?

Comment: @ChrisJ.Lee Yes, it's a bash built-in, it's available anywhere you're running bash.

Comment: Ah thanks. I thought the mac port may have some differences in commands. I guess that's just a misunderstanding on my part.