# How can I delete a word backward at the command line (bash and zsh)?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I delete a word backward at the command line?  I'm truly used to some editors deleting the last 'word' using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>, and I'd like that functionality at the command line too.

I am using Bash at the moment and although I could jump backward a word and then delete forward a word, I'd rather have this as a quick-key, or event as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

How can accomplish this?

Comment: Similar question on Stack Overflow (the answer is in that question): *[On the Bash command-line, how do you cut the word immediately after the cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334750)*

Answer (score 345, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is the standard "kill word" (aka `werase`).
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> kills the whole line (`kill`).

You can change them with `stty`.

```
-bash-4.2$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; 24 rows; 80 columns;
lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe -echok echoke -echonl echoctl
        -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo
        -extproc -xcase
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr -iuclc ixon -ixoff ixany imaxbel
        -ignbrk brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr -ocrnl -onocr -onlret -olcuc oxtabs -onoeot
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
        eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
        min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = <undef>;
        stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
-bash-4.2$ stty werase ^p
-bash-4.2$ stty kill ^a
-bash-4.2$
```

Note that one does not have to put the actual control character on the line, `stty` understands putting `^` and then the character you would hit with control.

After doing this, if I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> it will erase a word from the line.  And if I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, it will erase the whole line.

Comment: Using the `stty` command I attempted to assign the "kill word" to `Ctrl+BckSpc` by typing `stty werase` followed by Ctrl-v Ctrl-Backspace.  This inserts the literal Ctrl-Backspace character as the argument for `stty werase`.  Unfortunately it does not require typing `Ctrl-Backspace` to delete the word but works with just the `Backspace` key.  So I would like to second the request of @terdon to learn how to do this.  To reset the `werase` to default, use `stty werase Ctrl-v Ctrl-w`.

Comment: @TimothyMartin I'm a little stuck on how to do `ctrl-backspace`.  Backspace is generally sent as either `ctrl-h` or `ctrl-?`, so `ctrl-backspace` would somehow be `ctrl-ctrl-backspace`.  I did try to figure out if something different was sent, but putty, at least, just sends backspace when you type `ctrl-backspace`.

Comment: ctrl + w effectively deletes the word but it also copies to the clipboard, erasing anything you had stored (or pushing it down?).

Comment: Anyone know how to make the 'word' stop at non word characters rather than only white spaces? IE with: 'curl a/asdf/xcvb', pressing ^w will get 'curl', but what I want is 'curl a/asdf/'

Comment: esc - delete just worked :-)

Comment: In my case, Ctrl+P cycles through previous commands like ArrowUp `↑` does.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that despite this answer being accepted and the 200 upvotes no one ever figured out how to map backward delete word to CTRL+Backspace. (I have that combination setup everywhere else so I would really like to keep it.)

Comment: @Kvothe OP is not asking for it; however there are ways to remap keys in bash, see for example [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29231/remapping-ctrl-l-in-bash) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183857/remap-return-key-in-terminal-to-prevent-accidental-command-on-productions-server) [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/598222/how-do-i-remap-control-w-in-bash) or [the answer below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94388/296692).

Comment: Ctrl+W closed the tab in Solar-Putty

Answer (score 92):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> works for me in bash and zsh.

Comment: Doesnt work with iterm :(

Comment: For example deleting a URL and using `Ctrl+W` it deletes the whole URL while `Alt+Backspace` deletes a word and it stops deleting when a special character is found.

Comment: And [as always](https://www.skorks.com/2009/09/bash-shortcuts-for-maximum-productivity/) you have `ctrl-y` to yank/undo/paste.

Comment: This solves it for iterm: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2124

Comment: Ctrl+W close tab in cmder.

Comment: This is great for virtual terminals accessed via browser windows as `Ctrl+W` closes current chrome tab.

Comment: I think this doesn't work on Mac (not surprising).

Answer (score 44):

You can also do this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>.

Another option is to set your own shortcut but this will depend on the terminal emulator you are using. For `xterm` and `rxvt` and maybe others, add this line to your `~/.inputrc` (create the file if it does not exist):

```
## rxvt, xterm
"\b":backward-kill-word
```

`gnome-terminal` and its ilk seem to have <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd> by default but [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2715537/1081936) require you to patch `readline()` in order to get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

Also see:

- https://superuser.com/questions/95626/control-backspace-unix-kill-rubout-for-readline
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToReadline < for `konsole`

Answer (score 15):

In Ubuntu 18.04.4 pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> reveals that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> combination is written as `^H`.

You can show all current terminal key combinations using `stty -a`. In this case we want to change `werase` to `^H` which can be done with

```
stty werase ^H
```

For any other key you want to remap you would again see how to write the new combination using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by the combination.

And you can find the command name (such as `werase`) by looking at `stty -a` and looking for the key combination an action is currently bound to.

Comment: It's 2020 and we can use backspace correctly on Linux :). The good news is I don't think this is specific to Ubuntu (see https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~mcrob/toolbox/unix/keyboard.html for some info). I've tried several different terminal emulators on arch and ^H works in each case.

Comment: My man! How does this only have +6? Works on Cygwin as well.

Comment: And on Git Bash <3. Finally I have the same combination of keys in each shell. Great thanks! For anyone wondering how to do this for forward delete (CTRL + DEL), it's: `bind '"5~": kill-word'`

Answer (score 2):

On Mac, you can use:

<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>

Comment: That deletes 1 character in front of the cursor, not 1 word behind

Comment: Don't know if this is still relevant, but that would be <Alt> + <Backspace> on Mac.

Comment: <OPTION> <DELETE>

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, <kbd>esc</kbd> then <kbd>delete</kbd> works on macOS too.

Also, if using **iTerm2**, you can update the default **profile**:

```
Keys > Key Mapping > Presets > Natural Text Editing
```