# Remap Return key in terminal to prevent accidental command on productions servers

Tags: bash, key-mapping, readline

I am looking for a way to remap the key for executing commands in terminal (I am using bash) to prevent accidental commands on productions servers. Return should be disabled.

I tried the following in .inputrc

```
 RET : "Disabled"
 "\C-e" : "\r"
```

But that did not work because Return was mapped back to disabled.

Full .inputrc

```
#set editing-mode vi
TAB: menu-complete
RET: ""
"\C-e": "\C-j"
"\e[Z": menu-complete-backward
"\C-w": forward-word
"\C-g": forward-word
"\C-g": "gd\015"
"\C-o": "h\015"
#"\C-b": backward-word
"\C-3": backward-char


set show-all-if-ambiguous on
set completion-ignore-case on
set meta-flag on
set input-meta on
set convert-meta on
set output-meta on


#"\C-pp": "cd -\015"
"\M-p": "cd -\015"
"\M-o": "ls\015"

"\C-w": forward-word

$if mode=vi
    set keymap vi-command
    "gg": beginning-of-history
    "G": end-of-history
    set keymap vi-insert       #notice how the "jj" movement is
    "jj": vi-movement-mode     #after 'set keymap vi-insert'?
    "\C-w": backward-kill-word
    "\C-p": history-search-backward
$endif
```

Comment: I know several ways to do this in an X environment, but you usually don't have that on a server. I found this which might set you off in the right direction. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1021839#p1021839

Comment: have you tried something in this line? `trap 'read -p "are you sure?" str;if [[ "$str" != "y" ]];then kill -SIGINT $$;fi' DEBUG`, requires confirmation for every command (but this is just a scratch)

Answer (score 3):

`RET : ""`

Then use C-j from now on to enter commands.

Comment: That works, but I have to hit \C-j twice to enter, any idea why ?

Comment: What is your .inputrc? the order is significant in strange cases. You might also try \C-m

Answer (score 0):

To disable the Return key you can add the following to to your `.inputrc`:

```
"\C-m":""
```

Now use `C-j` to execute commands.

To avoid hitting `C-j` twice when you incremental search the history (e.g. via `C-r`) additionally add the following line:

```
set isearch-terminators '\C-['
```

This leaves `Esc` for terminating the search and `C-j` for `accept-line`.

See `man 3 readline` for more details.