# How do I remap Control-w in Bash?

Tags: bash, inputrc

I have read a number of answers to similar questions both in this forum and elsewhere, but I cannot make it work for me.

I am trying to remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to delete the word *forward* rather than backward. I know that I can use <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> do do this, but this is also a learning exercise for me.

Using what I have read, I have added the following in `~/.inputrc`:

```
$include /etc/inputrc
Control-w: kill-word
```

- The first line is, apparently, required if I want to include the other bindings.
- For the second, I have tried `Control-w` and `"\C-w"`, and for the command, I have tried `kill-word` and `shell-kill-word`.
- To try out the changes I have tried `bind -f  ~/.inputrc`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, `bash -l` and simply opening up a new terminal.

I assume that I have missed some important step, or simply misunderstood, but I’m running out of ideas.

I am on Centos 8.

Comment: Have you tried `Control-W`?

Comment: Did you see this post on SO? https://stackoverflow.com/q/10980575

Comment: The question about re-binding `^C-w` has answers, but it'd also be great to know where the precedence of terminal driver settings over Readline bindings is documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The readline library (which is what `inputrc` configures) sets up bindings corresponding to the bindings of the [terminal driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_mode) for cooked input. These are commonly known as stty keys because they can be configured with the command `stty`. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is the binding for deleting the previous word (`werase`) in the cooked terminal interface.

Those bindings take precedence over explicit bindings in `.inputrc`. To turn off this behavior, add this line to your `.inputrc`:

```
set bind-tty-special-chars off
```

If you haven't configured non-default cooked terminal key bindings with `stty`, I think this won't affect your bash bindings.