# in bash, is there a shortcut to wipe out typed password?

Tags: shell, terminal, password

On the command line (usually bash, and somtimes zsh), I sometimes need to enter a password to authenticate myself. in fact, I need to do that several times a day.

Sometimes, you fail typing and instead of hitting return (which is bad sometimes as it is recorded by the server) and type it another time, is there a shortcut (like <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> for searching the history) to wipe out the typed password and start anew?

Comment: @roaima I think OP means to clear the password input *before* hitting enter (without interrupt and retry, or holding backspace etc)

Comment: @thanasisp that's what I was thinking as well - perhaps [How can I delete a word backward at the command line (bash and zsh)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94331/how-can-i-delete-a-word-backward-at-the-command-line-bash-and-zsh) is what the OP is looking for?

Comment: @steeldriver yes this seems to have more information.

Comment: My answer is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> just tested successfully, very useful ! It was found in the first question, while the second is unrelated. Thanks!