# Bash: delete backward until backslash

Tags: bash

I know I can delete backward one word at a time, but many times I just want to change part of a path. Is there a command in emacs and therefore keyboard command in bash to delete backward just until a slash?

`alt+w` does one word at a time: [How can I delete a word backward at the command line (bash and zsh)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94331/how-can-i-delete-a-word-backward-at-the-command-line-bash-and-zsh)

Comment: As you are talking about a *path*, I suppose you mean *slash*, not *backslash*

Comment: @Philippos. yep, edited.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I realized a simple solution.. basically to use `ctrl+left-arrow` to skip back to the point I want to change. Then press `ctrl+k` to delete forward.

(just an aside, `ctrl+left-arrow` doesnt always work on some terminals, GCP remote ssh shell for example, and I wonder why)

Comment: Depending on the terminal emulation used, the left-arrow-key may be sent as some escape sequence or as cltr-H (backspace), causing problems when trying to send ctrl-ctrl-H

Answer (score 0):

If you are in vi mode (`set -o vi`), you do <kbd>Esc</kbd> to return to normal mode, then `db` (`d`elete to `b`eginning).

If you are in emacs mode (typically the default), you can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> for backwards search, then `/` to search for the slash, finally <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to delete forward.

Comment: interesting.. good to know that Ctrl+R searches also searches the current line when there is one.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to properly configure *GNU-readline* (which handles text edition at *GNU-bash*'s prompt)

In Bash, you can type

```bash
bind '"\ew": backward-kill-word'
```

Then test.

To make this permanent, as a user, you can edit `~/.inputrc`, which takes priority over the system config in `/etc/inputrc`. You can `$include /etc/inputrc` in `~/.inputrc` to inherit from it.

You want to have this line:

```
"\ew": backward-kill-word
```

This often defaults to `unix-word-rubout`, or even a shell or bash prefixed macro, which takes only white space as a delimiter. But `backward-kill-word` will take anything that is "not a letter nor a digit".

Refer to `man 3 readline` for full documentation.